# Is LLVM IR a machine independent language?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

When I was reading LLVM IR code (transformed from C), I saw an instruction like this:

```
%div = sdiv i32 %add, %32
```

The C code of this instruction may be like this:

```c
a = c / b;
```

We can see that there is a type `i32` in this instruction. This is because of the type of variables `a, b, c` are `int`.  And my computer is x86.

Now, if I have a machine where the integer is about 8 bits and I write the C code same as above and transform C to LLVM IR on this machine, the LLVM IR instruction might be `%div = sdiv i8 %add, %32`.

Is this right? If yes, how can we say that the LLVM IR is a **machine independent language**?

I thought that if a piece of code is in a machine independent language, then this code can run on any machine in this world, and when the code is running, the virtual machine or other things will handle the differences between architectures.

Comment: What do you mean by “a machine [where] the integer is about 8 bits”? If you’re referring to `int`, the answer is that it’s a C type, not a machine type. If you compile with a 32-bit `int`, LLVM will implement 32-bit integer operations for whatever supported platform you target. (Note: an `int` can’t be 8 bits in standard C, but it can be as low as 16.)

Comment: @Ry-♦ I mean, if I want to run the instruction` %div = sdiv i32 %add, %32` on a machine that the size of `int is 8 bits`, how will the virtual machine or other things (like code generation) do to handle such case?

Comment: So, again, `int` is a C type. Its size depends on the C compiler, not the machine the compiled program runs on. The same C code compiling to different LLVM IR depending on which compiler configuration you use doesn’t really say anything about LLVM IR.

Comment: It seems that there is some confusion here. C standard doesn't define the `int` size, that can vary from machine to machine, and compiler. Rewrite your source defining `a`, `b` and `c` as `int32_t` then check again the IR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, LLVM IR is a machine independent language.

But the IR code could not be run directly on real hardware. In order to run the IR code, a retarget process is needed. During 'retarget', the machine independent IR code is translated to machine dependent code for the target(x86, MIPS, aarch, 8bit chip and so on).

Comment: So, if I want to run the instruction `%div = sdiv i32 %add, %32` on a machine that the size of `int` is 8 bits, what is the process to retarget?

Comment: A possible solution of the retarget:  Use a loop to do 32bit math operations with 8 bit accumulator and registers.  Similar to the 32bit C Language statements being compiled to  8bit machine code.

Answer (score 3):

LLVM IR is a machine independent *language*, but that's not enough for machine independent *programs*. Programs require more than just a language. LLVM has classes called TargetMachine and DataLayout, for example, that collect target-specific details such as how structs are laid out in memory and whether pointers to odd-numbered addresses are legal. You'll often see code in that machine-independent language using target-dependent numbers. On this platform the code adds 4, on that other, 8.

But in both cases the language is the same and the `add` instruction is the same, which simplifies life for compiler maintainers.

Comment: Thanks. I did leave out details, though… let's say that I tried to balance clarity against detail.

Answer (score 1):

> Is LLVM IR a machine independent language?

If you compile source code that was written in assembly language (e.g. inline assembly) it can't be machine independent.

Therefore LLVM is machine independent (for most things) **and also** machine dependent (for assembly language).

Note that if you look at the LLVM reference (e.g.  http://web.cs.ucla.edu/classes/spring08/cs259/llvm-2.2/docs/LangRef.html#inlineasm ) you'll see that assembly language mostly becomes/remains plain text (not byte-code, not machine code). It's the contents of the plain text that's machine dependent (for the instructions themselves, and the constraints, etc).